# Configure CakePhp to send mail with SMTP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My web servers have disabled mail for security purposes I now need to reconfigure my cakephp code to send the emails via SMTP as recommended by the host.

My code runs fine on localhost with php mail enabled

```
use Cake\Mailer\Email;

class LoansController extends AppController

public function sendtestemail(){
$email = new Email();
$email->setViewVars(['name' => 'test test', 'subject'=>'subject test', 
'message'=>'testit']);
$email
->template('bulkemail')
->emailFormat('html')
->to('info@test.co.ke')
->from('info@test.co.ke')
->subject($subject)
->send();
}
```

error:
Could not send email: mail() has been disabled for security reasons
Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My code runs fine on localhost with php mail enabled

It works fine in localhost but not in your remote hosting because your hosting company disabled it and you *probably* do not have much control over it.

To send an email in cakephp use Email class of Cakephp 3. In app.php under config folder, add a new entry in the table EmailTransport.

In your case ‘Smtp’. Specify host, port, username and password in it:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 25,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
            ‘mail’=> [
                    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                    'port' => 587,
                    'username' =>xxxxx', //gmail id
                    'password' =>xxxxx, //gmail password
                    'tls' => true,
                    'className' => 'Smtp'
            ]
    ],
```

Now in Controller, the function to send email uses above-written entry in transport() function as below.

Add path in controller- use Cake\Mailer\Email:

```
function sendEmail()
{           
           $message = "Hello User";            
            $email = new Email();
            $email->transport('mail');
            $email->from(['Sender_Email_id' => 'Sender Name'])
            ->to('Receiver_Email_id')
            ->subject(‘Test Subject’)
            ->attachments($path) //Path of attachment file
            ->send($message);

}
```

Also have in mind that many hosting companies also **block** default smtp ports. ( I'm aware that digital ocean does it, for example ). So, you might have to change that port or contact them to get it opened for you ( usually after some sort of verification ).

Some reference about what I just answered: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/digital-ocean-firewall-blocking-sending-email

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 'className' => 'Mail', needs to be 'className' => 'Smtp', It works

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is from  https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

Edit /app/Config/email.php

```
public $smtp = array(
       'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com' => 'Betting site'),
        'host'      => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port'      => 465,
        'username'  => 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
        'password'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxpass',
        'client'    => null,
        'log'       => true
        );
```